# Is it possible to use Chrome Live Caption programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome, voice-recognition

Chrome 89 has a [Live Caption](https://blog.google/products/chrome/live-caption-chrome/) feature, which can transcribe English text from an audio/video as it plays. It even works offline, so it's not contacting Google's servers.

Is there any way to use this feature programmatically, e.g. to give it an audio file and capture the transcribed text?

**EDIT:** [This guy](https://hackaday.io/project/164399-android-offline-speech-recognition-natively-on-pc/log/187063-soda-finally-landed-client-working) wrote some code that lets you do it. But you need to figure out how to disassemble and patch Google's libsoda yourself. I did get it working though.

Comment: Do you have any examples on how to get it working?

Comment: For anyone still interested, [whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper) can do the same thing, and without any hacking.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying run puppeteer on Chrome and take an screenshoots each 250 milliseconds, but live caption it is not available to be enabled by going to Settings, then the “Advanced” section, and then “Accessibility.”

At least I wanted to get the images to use an OCR service to obtain the texts.

[image: Chrome Accessibility using Puppeteer]